# In Java, how to check that AutoCloseable.close() has been called?

Tags: java, dispose, try-with-resources, finalize, autocloseable

I am authoring a java library. Some of the classes that are meant to be used by library users, hold native system resources (over JNI). I'd like to ensure that the user "disposes" these objects, as they are heavy, and in a testsuite they may cause leakage between testcases (for example, I need to ensure `TearDown` will dispose). For this purpose I made the Java classes implement AutoCloseable, but this doesn't seem to suffice, or I'm not using it correctly:

1. I don't see how to use `try-with-resources` statement in the context of tests (I'm using `JUnit5` with `Mockito`), in that the "resource" is not short-lived - it is part of the test fixture.
2. Being diligent as always, I tried implementing `finalize()` and testing for closure there, but it turns out `finalize()` is not even called (Java10). This is also marked as deprecated and I'm sure this idea will be frowned upon.

How is this done? **To be clear, I want the application's tests (that use my library) to fail if they don't call `close()` on my objects.**

---

**Edit:** adding some code if it helps. It's not much, but it's what I'm trying to do.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation") // finalize() provided just to assert closure (deprecated starting Java 9)
@Override
protected final void finalize() throws Throwable {
    if (nativeHandle_ != 0) {
         // TODO finalizer is never called, how to assert that close() gets called?
        throw new AssertionError("close() was not called; native object leaking");
    }
}
```

---

**Edit2, outcome of bounty** Thanks all for replying, half the bounty was automatically awarded. I concluded that for my case it would be best to try the solution involving `Cleaner`. However it seems, cleaning actions although registered, are not invoked. I asked a follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54651773/why-is-cleaner-action-not-invoked).

Comment: Your library’s tests do not need to fail if the resources are not closed. Since that close operation is explicitly exposed to the user, this is something *their* tests should check for. You may, however, wish to test that calling a close operation actually closes the system resources, but in this instance you can explicitly close the resource in your test

Comment: is your question only about tests or about forcing to use #close method in general?

Comment: Sounds like you want to test this from your _application's_ tests, not from the library's own tests. In that case you could very well mock the AutoCloseable objects and just check that the mocked `close` methods are called when you expect them to be. There are many ways to mock that, Mockito, JMock...

Comment: @MTCoster the question is about "their" tests basically. My class exposes the `close()` method and not calling it amounts to incorrect use of my API. So I'd like to somehow bring attention to this error before going to the next testcase. Can this be done somehow? I'm flexible in that I _could_ a different similar mechanism/interface if it heps

Comment: @AdamSkywalker so the question applies to use of my API in general but I'm illustrating with tests. Application should close, nasty things can happen if not. To exemplify what I mean by this, think SO_LINGER for TCP connections. On the native side I have things like state machines that need to enter certain final states (you may say what if they don't since application is closing anyway? well not quite, sometimes you need "closure" to ensure all data has been transmitted between peers that are networking)

Comment: From [the docs on `AutoClosable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html#close--): “*Note that unlike the `close` method of `Closeable`, this `close` method is not required to be idempotent. In other words, calling this `close` method more than once may have some visible side effect, unlike `Closeable.close` which is required to have no effect if called more than once.*” - You could throw a `ResourceAlreadyClosedException` after the first call to `close`, then instruct users to check for that exception in their tests

Comment: That's a good point, and I'm handling the case of `close()` being called twice, but my question is about `close()` being called zero times.

Comment: So your core issue is to call `close` before shutdown? I'd probably explore the combination of shutdown hook and a static weak reference list to the must-close class instances

Comment: Seems more like something the compiler should warn about rather than something that would need to be implemented at runtime. I think all streams will be closed by the OS if the JVM is shutting down entirely though.

Comment: @haelix Regarding `finalize`- there's a new thingie called [`Cleaner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html) which is preferred to finalizers these days. It also plays nice with autocloseables, as can be seen in the example on the API page. There's still no guarantees as to when or even if they will run, though (unless you manually invoke the cleanup).

Answer (score 18):

*This post does not directly answer your question but provides a different point of view.*

One approach to make your clients consistently call `close` is to free them from this responsibility.

#### How can you do it?

Use template pattern.

#### Sketch implementation

You mentioned that you're working with TCP, so let's assume that you have a `TcpConnection` class that has a `close()` method.

Let's define `TcpConnectionOperations` interface:

```
public interface TcpConnectionOperations {
  <T> T doWithConnection(TcpConnectionAction<T> action);
}
```

and implement it:

```
public class TcpConnectionTemplate implements TcpConnectionOperations {
  @Override
  public <T> T doWithConnection(TcpConnectionAction<T> action) {
    try (TcpConnection tcpConnection = getConnection()) {
      return action.doWithConnection(tcpConnection);
    }
  }
}
```

`TcpConnectionAction` is just a callback, nothing fancy.

```
public interface TcpConnectionAction<T> {
  T doWithConnection(TcpConnection tcpConnection);
}
```

#### How the library should be consumed now?

- It must be consumed *only* through `TcpConnectionOperations` interface.
- Consumers supply actions

For example:

```
String s = tcpConnectionOperations.doWithConnection(connection -> {
  // do what we with with the connection
  // returning to string for example
  return connection.toString();
});
```

#### Pros

- Clients don't have to worry about:
- - getting a `TcpConnection`
- - closing the connection
- You are in control of creating connections:
- - you can cache them
- - log them
- - collect statistics
- - many other use cases...
- In tests you can provide mock `TcpConnectionOperations` and mock `TcpConnections` and make assertions against them

#### Cons

This approach may not work if the lifecycle of a resource is longer than `action`. E.g. it is necessary for the client to keep the resource for a longer time.

Then you might want to dive deep in [`ReferenceQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html)/[`Cleaner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html) (since Java 9) and related API.

#### Inspired by Spring framework

This pattern is widely used in [Spring framework](https://spring.io).

See for example:

- [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html)
- [`TransactionTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html)
- [`JmsTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html).
- (there are many others)

#### Update 2/7/19

#### How can I cache/reuse the resource?

This is some kind of [pooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_(computer_science)):

> a pool is a collection of resources that are kept ready to use, rather than acquired on use and released

Some *pools* in Java:

- [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) is a JDBC connection pool library
- [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)s [`ConnectionPool`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/5c0591b13559565de42bbb845519438adec6395b/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/ConnectionPool.java)
- Tomcat JDBC Connection pool
- [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

When implementing a pool several questions are raised:

- When the resource actually should be `close`d?
- How the resource should be shared between multiple threads?

**When the resource should be `close`d?**

Usually pools provide an explicit *`close`* method (it may have a different name but the purpose is the same) which closes all the resources held.

- [`HikariDataSource#close`](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/b39141bfd55acae059551556de4406ee547cfb55/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariDataSource.java#L341)
- [`ConnectionPool#evictAll`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ConnectionPool.html#evictAll--) "Close and remove all idle connections in the pool."
- [`ConnectionPool#close`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/ConnectionPool.html#close(boolean))
- [`ThreadPoolExecutor#shutdown`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown--)

**How it can be shared across multiple threads?**

It depends on a kind of the resource itself.

Usually you want to ensure that only one thread accesses one resource.

This can be done using some kind of locking

#### Demo

*Note that code provided here is only for demonstration purposes
It has awful performance and violates some OOP principles.*

`IpAndPort.java`

```
@Value
public class IpAndPort {
  InetAddress address;
  int port;
}
```

`TcpConnection.java`

```
@Data
public class TcpConnection {
  private static final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

  private final IpAndPort ipAndPort;
  private final long instance = counter.incrementAndGet();

  public void close() {
    System.out.println("Closed " + this);
  }
}
```

`CachingTcpConnectionTemplate.java`

```
public class CachingTcpConnectionTemplate implements TcpConnectionOperations {
  private final Map<IpAndPort, TcpConnection> cache
      = new HashMap<>();
  private boolean closed; 
  public CachingTcpConnectionTemplate() {
    System.out.println("Created new template");
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized <T> T doWithConnectionTo(IpAndPort ipAndPort, TcpConnectionAction<T> action) {
    if (closed) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Closed");
    }
    TcpConnection tcpConnection = cache.computeIfAbsent(ipAndPort, this::getConnection);
    try {
      System.out.println("Executing action with connection " + tcpConnection);
      return action.doWithConnection(tcpConnection);
    } finally {
      System.out.println("Returned connection " + tcpConnection);
    }
  }

  private TcpConnection getConnection(IpAndPort ipAndPort) {
    return new TcpConnection(ipAndPort);
  }


  @Override
  public synchronized void close() {
    if (closed) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("closed");
    }
    closed = true;
    for (Map.Entry<IpAndPort, TcpConnection> entry : cache.entrySet()) {
      entry.getValue().close();
    }
    System.out.println("Template closed");
  }
}
```

Tests infrastructure

`TcpConnectionOperationsParameterResolver.java`

```
public class TcpConnectionOperationsParameterResolver implements ParameterResolver, AfterAllCallback {
  private final CachingTcpConnectionTemplate tcpConnectionTemplate = new CachingTcpConnectionTemplate();

  @Override
  public boolean supportsParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
    return parameterContext.getParameter().getType().isAssignableFrom(CachingTcpConnectionTemplate.class)
        && parameterContext.isAnnotated(ReuseTemplate.class);
  }

  @Override
  public Object resolveParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
    return tcpConnectionTemplate;
  }

  @Override
  public void afterAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
    tcpConnectionTemplate.close();
  }
}
```

The [`ParameterResolver`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ParameterResolver.html) and [`AfterAllCallback`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/AfterAllCallback.html) are from JUnit.

`@ReuseTemplate` is a custom annotation

`ReuseTemplate.java`:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ReuseTemplate {
}
```

Finally test:

```
@ExtendWith(TcpConnectionOperationsParameterResolver.class)
public class Tests2 {
  private final TcpConnectionOperations tcpConnectionOperations;

  public Tests2(@ReuseTemplate TcpConnectionOperations tcpConnectionOperations) {
    this.tcpConnectionOperations = tcpConnectionOperations;
  }

  @Test
  void google80() throws UnknownHostException {
    tcpConnectionOperations.doWithConnectionTo(new IpAndPort(InetAddress.getByName("google.com"), 80), tcpConnection -> {
      System.out.println("Using " + tcpConnection);
      return tcpConnection.toString();
    });
  }

  @Test
  void google80_2() throws Exception {
    tcpConnectionOperations.doWithConnectionTo(new IpAndPort(InetAddress.getByName("google.com"), 80), tcpConnection -> {
      System.out.println("Using " + tcpConnection);
      return tcpConnection.toString();
    });
  }

  @Test
  void google443() throws Exception {
    tcpConnectionOperations.doWithConnectionTo(new IpAndPort(InetAddress.getByName("google.com"), 443), tcpConnection -> {
      System.out.println("Using " + tcpConnection);
      return tcpConnection.toString();
    });
  }
}
```

Running:

```
$ mvn test
```

Output:

```
Created new template
[INFO] Running Tests2
Executing action with connection TcpConnection(ipAndPort=IpAndPort(address=google.com/74.125.131.102, port=80), instance=1)
Using TcpConnection(ipAndPort=IpAndPort(address=google.com/74.125.131.102, port=80), instance=1)
Returned connection TcpConnection(ipAndPort=IpAndPort(address=google.com/74.125.131.102, port=80), instance=1)
Executing action with connection TcpConnection(ipAndPort=IpAndPort(address=google.com/74.125.131.102, port=443), instance=2)
Using TcpConnection(ipAndPort=IpAndPort(address=google.com/74.125.131.102, port=443), instance=2)
Returned connection TcpConnection(ipAndPort=IpAndPort(address=google.com/74.125.131.102, port=443), instance=2)
Executing action with connection TcpConnection(ipAndPort=IpAndPort(address=google.com/74.125.131.102, port=80), instance=1)
Using TcpConnection(ipAndPort=IpAndPort(address=google.com/74.125.131.102, port=80), instance=1)
Returned connection TcpConnection(ipAndPort=IpAndPort(address=google.com/74.125.131.102, port=80), instance=1)
Closed TcpConnection(ipAndPort=IpAndPort(address=google.com/74.125.131.102, port=80), instance=1)
Closed TcpConnection(ipAndPort=IpAndPort(address=google.com/74.125.131.102, port=443), instance=2)
Template closed
```

The key observation here is that connections are reused (see "`instance=`")

*This is oversimplified example of what can be done. Sure, in the real world pooling connections is not so simple. 
The pool should not grow indefinitely, connections can be kept only for specific period of time and so on. 
Usually some problems are solved by having something in the background.*

#### Returning to the question

> I don't see how to use `try-with-resources statement` in the context of tests (I'm using `JUnit5` with `Mockito`), in that the "resource" is not short-lived - it is part of the test fixture.

See [Junit 5 User Guide. Extension model](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions)

> Being diligent as always, I tried implementing `finalize()` and testing for closure there, but it turns out `finalize()` is not even called (Java10). This is also marked as deprecated and I'm sure this idea will be frowned upon.

You overrode `finalize` so that it throws an exception but they are ignored.

See [`Object#finalize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize())

> If an uncaught exception is thrown by the finalize method, the exception is ignored and finalization of that object terminates.

The best you can do here is to log the resource leakage and `close` the resource

> To be clear, I want the application's tests (that use my library) to fail if they don't call `close()` on my objects.

How do application tests use your resource? Do they instantiate it using `new` operator?
If yes then I think [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock) can help you (but I'm not sure)

If you have hidden instantiation of the resource behind some kind of a factory then you can give the application tests some mock factory

---

If you're interested you can watch this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpqDAkGRSTk). It's in Russian, but still may be helpful (part of my answer is based on this talk).

Comment: What would you recommend if the resource should be shared among threads, or should be mixed with other transactions?

Comment: @gaborsch I think it depends on what kind of a resource is shared... Do you have a scenario similar to some kind of connection pooling? Then you can check how, for example HikariCP manages the connections. `OkHttpClient`'s `ConnectionPool` can also give some insight. If you have something dealing with concurrent writing/reading then you'll have to deal with `ReadWriteLock`. But when, how and which thread should close the resource depends on particular use case...

Comment: _you can cache them_ - no you can't, if you cache them, you have no idea when to `close()` them, and we're back to the problem. Of course the resource is long-lived, the questions mentions this.

Answer (score 6):

If I were you, I'd do the following:

- Write a static wrapper around your calls that returns "heavy" objects
- Create a collection of **PhantomReferences** to hold all your heavy objects, for cleanup purposes
- Create a collection of **WeakReferences** to hold all your heavy objects, to check whether they are GC'd or not (have any reference from the caller or not)
- At teardown I would check the wrapper to see what resources have been GC'd (have reference in the Phantom, but not in the Weak), and I'd check whether they have been closed or nor properly.
- If you add some debug/caller/stacktrace information while serving the resource, it will be easier to trace back the leaking test case.

It also depends whether you want to use this mechanism in production or not - maybe it is worth to add this feature to your lib, because resource management will be a problem in production environment, too. In this case you don't need a wrapper, but you can extend your current classes with this feature. Instead of a teardown, you can use a background thread for regular checks.

Regarding reference types, I recommend [this link](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/03/difference-between-weakreference-vs-softreference-vs-phantomreference-vs-strong-reference-in-java.html). PhantomReferences are recommended to use for resource cleanups.

Comment: I think a solution involving Phantom or Weak is the way to go, basically some kind of notification mechanism so my lib _knows_ when does the user no longer hold a Strong ref. _At that point, she should have closed()_ the resource, otherwise the library unleashes hell.

Comment: "Should have closed()" - if they haven't, in tests you can mark that case failed, in production you can silently close it for them, freeing the resource.

Comment: _silently close it for them_ - this is not an option in my case. The native object is sensitive and needs to be closed from thread which created it, which may be a user thread. Hopefully this sheds more light into why the user really must close the thing deterministically, and why the whole discussion

Comment: I see. In this case I would consider two options: 1) create a manager thread that creates and closes the objects on request, that would work even in prod environment, 2) trace the thread and the stacktrace where individual.objects were created, and report them when failure detected. That will help bug detection.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in consistency in tests, just add method `destroy()` marked by `@AfterClass` annotation into test class and close all previously allocated resources in it.

If you are interested in an approach that allow you to protect the resource from being not closed, you could provide a way that doesn't expose resource to user explicitly. For example, you code could control resource life cycle and accept only `Consumer<T>` from user.

If you can't do that, but still want to be sure that resource will be closed even if user doesn't use it correctly you'll have to do several tricky things. You could split your resource on `sharedPtr` and `resource` itself. Then expose `sharedPtr` to user and put it into some internal storage wrapped into `WeakReference`. As result of that you'll be able to catch the moment when GC removes `sharedPtr` and call `close()` on the `resource`. Be aware that `resource` must not be exposed to user. I prepared an example, it's not very accurate, but hope it shows the idea:

```java
public interface Resource extends AutoCloseable {

    public int jniCall();
}
```

```java
class InternalResource implements Resource {

    public InternalResource() {
        // Allocate resources here.
        System.out.println("Resources were allocated");
    }

    @Override public int jniCall() {
        return 42;
    }

    @Override public void close() {
        // Dispose resources here.
        System.out.println("Resources were disposed");
    }
}
```

```java
class SharedPtr implements Resource {

    private final Resource delegate;

    public SharedPtr(Resource delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override public int jniCall() {
        return delegate.jniCall();
    }

    @Override public void close() throws Exception {
        delegate.close();
    }
}
```

```java
public class ResourceFactory {

    public static Resource getResource() {
        InternalResource resource = new InternalResource();
        SharedPtr sharedPtr = new SharedPtr(resource);

        Thread watcher = getWatcherThread(new WeakReference<>(sharedPtr), resource);
        watcher.setDaemon(true);
        watcher.start();

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(resource::close));

        return sharedPtr;
    }

    private static Thread getWatcherThread(WeakReference<SharedPtr> ref, InternalResource resource) {
        return new Thread(() -> {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && ref.get() != null)
                LockSupport.parkNanos(1_000_000);

            resource.close();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you could reliably test whether a resource has been closed, you could just close it yourself.

The first thing to do is to make handling resource easy for the client. Use the Execute Around idiom.

As far as I know, the only use of execute around for resource handling  in the Java library is `java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged` and that's special (the resource is a magic stack frame, that you *really* don't want to leave open). I believe Spring has long had a much-needed JDBC library for this. I was certainly using execute-around (didn't know it was called that at the time) for JDBC shortly after Java 1.1 made it vaguely practical.

The library code should look something like:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface WithMyResource<R> {
    R use(MyResource resource) throws MyException;
}
public class MyContext {
// ...
    public <R> R doAction(Arg arg, WithMyResource<R> with) throws MyException {
        try (MyResource resource = acquire(arg)) {
            return with.use(resource);
        }
    }
```

(Do get the type parameter declarations in the right place.)

Client side usage looks something like:

```
MyType myResult = yourContext.doContext(resource -> {
    ...blah...;
    return ...thing...;
});
```

Back to testing. How do we make it easy to test even if the testee exfiltrates the resource from the execute around or some other mechanism is available?

The obvious answer is that you provide the execute around solution to the test. You will need to provide some execute around-using API to verify all of your resources that have been acquired in the scope have also been closed. This should be paired with the context the resource is acquired from rather than using global state.

Depending upon which testing framework your clients are using, you may be able to offer something better. JUnit5, for instance, has an annotation-based extension facility which allows you to supply the context as an argument and also apply checks after each test has executed. (But I haven't used it much, so I'm not going to say anything more.)

Comment: _In general, if you could reliably test whether a resource has been closed, you could just close it yourself_ - false. This is not an option in my case. The native object is sensitive and needs to be closed from thread which created it, which may be a user thread. Hopefully this sheds more light into why the user really must close the thing deterministically, and why the whole discussion

Answer (score 0):

i would provide instances to those objects through `Factory methods` and with that i have control over the creation of them, and i will feed the consumers with `Proxies` that does the logic of *closing* the object

```java
interface Service<T> {
 T execute();
 void close();
}

class HeavyObject implements Service<SomeObject> {
  SomeObject execute() {
  // .. some logic here
  }
  private HeavyObject() {}

  public static HeavyObject create() {
   return new HeavyObjectProxy(new HeavyObject());
  }

  public void close() {
   // .. the closing logic here
  }
}

class HeavyObjectProxy extends HeavyObject {

  public SomeObject execute() {
    SomeObject value = super.execute();
    super.close();
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to `close()` the resource after each operation.