# How to keep track if an instance has been closed with Java AutoCloseable?

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, finalizer, autocloseable

I'm reading [Effective Java by Joshua Bloch](https://www.amazon.com.au/Effective-Java-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0134685997/). In **ITEM 8: AVOID FINALIZERS AND CLEANERS** of **CHAPTER 2**, he highlights the problems with using finalizers and cleaners for memory management. This [article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-finalize) by Baeldung gives a good theoretical explanation of what finalizers entail. And an [answer by Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74559427/6367109) to my previous question excellently demonstrates the problems with the `finalize()`, particularly for security.

As a remedy for circumventing finalizers and cleaners, using `AutoCloseable` is recommended in the book:

> So what should you do instead of writing a finalizer or cleaner for a
> class whose objects encapsulate resources that require termination,
> such as files or threads? Just **have your class implement**
> `AutoCloseable`, and require its clients to invoke the `close` method
> on each instance when it is no longer needed, typically using
> `try`-with-resources to ensure termination even in the face of
> exceptions (Item 9).

However, he adds an ancillary point that we must keep track of whether the object has been closed, stating:

> One detail worth mentioning is that the instance must keep track of
> whether it has been closed: the close method must record in a field
> that the object is no longer valid, and other methods must check this
> field and throw an `IllegalStateException` if they are called after
> the object has been closed.

Unfortunately, he hasn't given a tangible example in code of how to do this when writing an API. I would really appreciate it if you could do so?

My research on this matter so far has been to no avail. One of the top-rated questions on this I found had an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54479104/6367109) that suggested an alternative method of freeing the client of this responsibility which perhaps is a better solution but still doesn't answer the question I have pertaining to what Joshua Bloch has stated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That seems pretty clear - just record in a variable when `close` has been called and then check that variable in other methods to know if those operations are valid.

Comment: `class Foo { boolean closed = false; public void close() { close = true; } public void doSomething() { if (closed) throw new IllegalStateException(); } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [ndc85430](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8152324/ndc85430) and [Louis Wasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869736/louis-wasserman), I managed to put together a working example. N.B. I repurposed Baeldung's [demo](https://www.baeldung.com/java-finalize#no-finalizer-example).

```
/** Example courtesy of Baeldung
 * Refer to unit test to see the client implementation.
 */
public class DemoClass implements AutoCloseable {
    /** Reads text from an input stream. */
    private BufferedReader reader;

    /** Flag that keeps track if resource has been closed. */
    boolean closed = false;

    /**
     * An object created from the Finalisable class
     * will create a new BufferedReader instance
     * that reads from the specified classpath.
     */
    public DemoClass() throws IOException {
        File initialFile = new File("src/main/java/Item8/finalisers/nietzsche.txt");
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
    }

    /** Reads first line from the text stream.*/
    public String readFirstLine() throws IOException {
        /** Checks if the resource is closed prior to accessing it. */
        if (closed) throw new IllegalStateException();
        return reader.readLine();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        /** closed flag is updated in the try-catch block. */
        try {
            reader.close();
            closed = true;
            System.out.println("Closed BufferedReader in the close method and flag changed to " + closed);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Didn't close, and the flag is still " + closed);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Full code, including unit tests, can be found [here](https://github.com/TRahulSam1997/Effective-Java-Joshua-Bloch/tree/main/src/main/java/Item8/finalisers/autocloseable).

Comment: You should not swallow the `IOException` thrown by `reader.close()`.

Comment: @Holger Thanks again for picking that out. I'm now throwing the exception.

Comment: @Holger Done! Does this look good?

Comment: That’s fine. You wouldn’t need it for a `BufferedReader`, as it tracks its close status anyway, but it’s good for demonstration purposes.